# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sortBy' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am using this code

```
var options = window.urlOptions;
console.log(options);
if('sortBy' in options)
{
  url = url + '&order=' . options.sortBy;
}
```

and it gives me the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sortBy' of undefined
```

However, the console.log(options) returns this:

```
Object {sortBy: "date__desc"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I am so stupid, I used . as concatenation operator as in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  url = url + '&order=' + options.sortBy;
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nwxzb/3/

Answer (score 1):

Change your if() {...}

as

```
if('sortBy' in options)
{
  url = url + '&order=' + options.sortBy;
}
```

You should appending your sortBy to URL by `+`, not `.`

So thats why it is showing **Uncaught TypeError**